# Why GAE ChannelAPI Socket.open() fails?

Tags: google-app-engine, titanium, appcelerator-mobile, channel-api

1. We are using Channel API on our website and it works very well on desktop and mobile site (iPhone/Android). But the same code fails silently on Socket.open command in our mobile app (built with Appcelerator Titanium/jQTouch/WebView). Unfortunately it's not possible to debug JavaScript in Titanium/WebViews. What are the possible causes of this?
2. What are the compatibility requirements for the JavaScript Client? In our test it didn't work on S60V5 browsers (Nokia N97/5800).
3. There was a bug with 'close' command which required to manually remove the iframe, is it fixed in latest release (1.4.2)?

Thanks.

Comment: Have the same issue with GWT 2.3 and GAE 1.4